# uibinder onload not call

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

if i call uibinder through  `new TheWidget();`    is onLoad() method is call right after TheWidget() is instantiationed  ?

```
public class TheWidget extends Composite {

}
```

in my test, onLoad() is not call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onLoad is called when your widget becomes attached to the browser document, not when it is constructed.

Try adding your widget to another attached widget:

```
TheWidget theWidget = new TheWidget();
RootPanel.get().add(theWidget);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use UiBinder inside `Composite` object then you should invoke it when object gets constructed - inside constructor. Take a look at the [Hello World](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_World).